# C/Linux Threads: count how many appearances of '1' are in the numbers from 1 to n

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, counting

So from the numbers from 1 to n, I have to compute how much the '1' digit occurs. For example: if n is 11, the total numbers is 4 (1, 10, 11). My assignment is saying that i have to use threads for this. This is what I've wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
    int from;
    int to;
} th_struct;

void *thread_function(void *param){
    th_struct *st = (th_struct *) param;
    int count = 0;
    int nr;

    for(int i = st->from; i <= st->to; i++){
        nr = i + 1;
        while(nr != 0 ){
            if (nr % 10 == 1)
                count++;
            nr /= 10;
        }
    }

    return (void *) (long) count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int threads, n, count = 0, result;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &threads);

    th_struct info[threads];
    pthread_t tid[threads];

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
        if(i == 0)
            info[0].from = 0;
        else
            info[i].from = info[i - 1].to + 1;

        info[i].to = info[i].from + n / threads - 1;

        if(i < n / threads)
            info[i].to++;

        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, &info[i]);
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
         pthread_join(tid[i], (void**)&result);
         count += (int) (long) result;
     } 

    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

First command line argument is n, and the second is the number of threads. For n equal to 11, the output should be 4. But if I plug in 11 1 (n=11, nr of threads=1) the output is 5 (instead of 4). If i plug in 11 2 (two threads), the output is 9. The output should be the same, no matter how many threads I have. 
 
I have tested the following code, and it works. It computes the number of '1' correctly (the following is the same as in the funcion "thread_function_ above", just adapted for testing):

```
int function(int n){
    int count = 0;
    int nr;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        nr = i + 1;
        while(nr != 0 ){
            if (nr % 10 == 1)
                count++;
            nr /= 10;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

So the problem is thread related (I guess). Since this is my first program with threads, I don't know what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Print out to/from as it is calculated.  Are those values sane?

Comment: First of all, your function without thread is not exact. Secondly, initialize the info before creating the threads. I test with n = 11, count = 5, n = 21, count = 13

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems:

1. Incorrect input ranges:

   ```
   info[0].from = 0;
   ...
   if(i < n / threads)
        info[i].to++;
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   info[i].from = 1;
   ...
   if (n % 2 == 1 && i + 1 == threads)
       info[i].to++;
   ```
2. Invalid range processing:

   `nr = i + 1;`

   Should be:

   `nr = i;`
3. Invalid result receiving.`i` changes its value while iterating for joining threads and for loop executes more times than intended:

   `pthread_join(tid[i], (void**)&result);`

   Should be:

   ```
   void* result;
   pthread_join(tid[i], &result);
   ```

Comment: can you explain how does declaring `result` as `void *` saves extra iterations?

Comment: @AdneshDhamangaonkar after returning from `thread_function()` 8 byte pointer (`void *`) assigns to 4 byte `result` and 4 byte `i` at `pthread_join()`. You can change `result` type to `uint64_t` and check it.